# SpringDBUnit ToleratedDelta - Assertion floating-point numbers

Tags: java, mysql, spring, assertions, dbunit

i have problem with floating point assertions in **SpringDBunit**. I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972579/dbunit-assertion-floating-point-numbers), but I am using MySql and cannot change DB layer. I've also checked [dbunit documentation](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#tolerateddelta), but no luck with that either and still getting assertion error:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: value (table=tablename, row=0, col=colname) 
Expected :0.35
Actual   :0.35000000000000003
```

Is there any way how to set "tolerance" for assertion in SpringDBUnit?

My MySqlDataFactory looks as follows:

```
//MySqlDataTypeFactory is taken from a context
ToleratedDeltaMap.ToleratedDelta toleratedDelta = new ToleratedDeltaMap.ToleratedDelta("tablename","colname",0.001);
mySqlDataTypeFactory.addToleratedDelta(toleratedDelta);
```

And `DatabaseConfigBean` is defined in context as follows:

```
<bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConfig" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseConfigBean">
    <property name="datatypeFactory" value="#{testDataTypeFactory.getMySqlDataTypeFactory()}" />-
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance.